# Ubuntu 17.04 x64 Desktop can not connect WIFI AP

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless, 17.04

My Laptop is T460 which has the intel 8260 wireless interface.

When it runs Ubuntu 16.10 x64 Desktop, it can connect to my AP WIFI (SSID is FET_Printer_Service), and my hot spot from my mobile phone

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 x64 Desktop, my laptop can not connect to my WIFI. But it still can connect to my hot spot from my mobile phone. the log is as below:

```
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7235] device (wlp3s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7236] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation') [100 110 60]
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7237] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka dbus[967]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka whoopsie[1005]: [08:25:30] offline
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7271] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="8ea3108e-a8e3-4a93-8f00-027d2fe0bea6" name="FET_Printer_Service" pid=2737 uid=1000 result="success"
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7279] device (wlp3s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation') [110 30 60]
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00011043
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00011043
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka avahi-daemon[1033]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::87b2:69d6:a28d:e792 on wlp3s0.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka avahi-daemon[1033]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::87b2:69d6:a28d:e792.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka avahi-daemon[1033]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka dbus[967]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7615] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 11847
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7615] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka deja-dup-monito[11363]: Source ID 194 was not found when attempting to remove it
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka kernel: [ 1012.007035] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 02:1a:11:f6:4a:ae by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka wpa_supplicant[1295]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=02:1a:11:f6:4a:ae reason=3 locally_generated=1
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001003
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka whoopsie[1005]: [08:25:30] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001003
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: Removing interface wlp3s0 index:3
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka kernel: [ 1012.020044] bridge-wlp3s0: disabling the bridge
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnet-natd: RTM_DELADDR: index:3, addr:192.168.1.17
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka avahi-daemon[1033]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.17 on wlp3s0.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka avahi-daemon[1033]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.17.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001002
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001002
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka avahi-daemon[1033]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7783] device (wlp3s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 4A:15:30:33:43:BE (scanning)
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka whoopsie[1005]: [08:25:30] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001003
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka kernel: [ 1012.027875] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7836] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7837] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'FET_Printer_Service' (8ea3108e-a8e3-4a93-8f00-027d2fe0bea6)
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <warn>  [1493079930.7843] sup-iface[0x557d95685ab0,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7843] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7854] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7855] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka kernel: [ 1012.033038] bridge-wlp3s0: down
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka kernel: [ 1012.033049] bridge-wlp3s0: detached
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: Stopped bridge wlp3s0 to virtual network 0.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001002
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7884] device (wlp3s0): set-hw-addr: set-cloned MAC address to F4:8C:50:61:19:8A (permanent)
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001002
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001002
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001003
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001002
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001002
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001002
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka whoopsie[1005]: [08:25:30] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7935] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001003
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp3s0 index:3 flags:0x00001003
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7939] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'FET_Printer_Service' has security, but secrets are required.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7939] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka kernel: [ 1012.037770] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.7997] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.8001] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.8003] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'FET_Printer_Service' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.8004] Config: added 'ssid' value 'FET_Printer_Service'
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.8004] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.8004] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.8004] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.8004] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079930.8024] sup-iface[0x557d95685ab0,wlp3s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka kernel: [ 1012.220111] userif-2: sent link down event.
    Apr 25 08:25:30 xwureka kernel: [ 1012.220115] userif-2: sent link up event.
    Apr 25 08:25:31 xwureka wpa_supplicant[1295]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 (SSID='FET_Printer_Service' freq=2452 MHz)
    Apr 25 08:25:31 xwureka kernel: [ 1013.030015] wlp3s0: authenticate with 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58
    Apr 25 08:25:31 xwureka kernel: [ 1013.038525] wlp3s0: send auth to 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 (try 1/3)
    Apr 25 08:25:31 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079931.8030] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
    Apr 25 08:25:31 xwureka kernel: [ 1013.046566] wlp3s0: authenticated
    Apr 25 08:25:31 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
    Apr 25 08:25:31 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka kernel: [ 1013.652894] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka kernel: [ 1013.652942] wlp3s0: Connection to AP 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 lost
    Apr 25 08:25:31 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:32 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:33 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka compiz[2658]: [11964:12003:0425/082535.817279:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(386)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.4.4.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8888.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 2001:4860:4860::8844.
    Apr 25 08:25:35 xwureka systemd-resolved[1166]: Switching to fallback DNS server 8.8.8.8.
    Apr 25 08:25:36 xwureka kernel: [ 1018.040199] wlp3s0: aborting authentication with 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    Apr 25 08:25:36 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079936.8123] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
    Apr 25 08:25:36 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079936.9129] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
    Apr 25 08:25:39 xwureka wpa_supplicant[1295]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 (SSID='FET_Printer_Service' freq=2452 MHz)
    Apr 25 08:25:39 xwureka kernel: [ 1020.668382] wlp3s0: authenticate with 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58
    Apr 25 08:25:39 xwureka kernel: [ 1020.676581] wlp3s0: send auth to 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 (try 1/3)
    Apr 25 08:25:39 xwureka kernel: [ 1020.679493] wlp3s0: authenticated
    Apr 25 08:25:39 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079939.4488] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
    Apr 25 08:25:39 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
    Apr 25 08:25:39 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    Apr 25 08:25:40 xwureka kernel: [ 1021.291141] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
    Apr 25 08:25:40 xwureka kernel: [ 1021.291204] wlp3s0: Connection to AP 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 lost
    Apr 25 08:25:44 xwureka kernel: [ 1025.679554] wlp3s0: aborting authentication with 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    Apr 25 08:25:39 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    Apr 25 08:25:44 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079944.4523] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
    Apr 25 08:25:44 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079944.9532] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
    Apr 25 08:25:45 xwureka wpa_supplicant[1295]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 (SSID='FET_Printer_Service' freq=2452 MHz)
    Apr 25 08:25:45 xwureka kernel: [ 1027.122858] wlp3s0: authenticate with 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58
    Apr 25 08:25:45 xwureka kernel: [ 1027.132614] wlp3s0: send auth to 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 (try 1/3)
    Apr 25 08:25:45 xwureka kernel: [ 1027.141686] wlp3s0: authenticated
    Apr 25 08:25:45 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079945.9096] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
    Apr 25 08:25:45 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
    Apr 25 08:25:45 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    Apr 25 08:25:46 xwureka kernel: [ 1027.747099] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
    Apr 25 08:25:46 xwureka kernel: [ 1027.747178] wlp3s0: Connection to AP 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 lost
    Apr 25 08:25:50 xwureka kernel: [ 1032.137521] wlp3s0: aborting authentication with 70:4d:7b:5d:48:58 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    Apr 25 08:25:45 xwureka nm-applet[2737]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    Apr 25 08:25:50 xwureka NetworkManager[987]: <info>  [1493079950.9110] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
```

Answer (score 7):

See launchpad.net bugs [1683836](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1683836), [1676547](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1676547), [1681513](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1681513). According to resolution found on them:

Use:

```
ifconfig
```

To determine your WiFi interface name (`wl...`)

Create:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/disable-random-mac.conf
```

With:

```
[device-wlan0]  
match-device=wlan0  
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

And replace both instances of `wlan0` above with the interface name you found earlier.

Restart network-manager service.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I was getting this issue intermittently and this worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks ! This works great for me (Debian Stretch)